# Score Columns in Azure ML Studio

Tags: predictive-modeling, feature-selection, azure-ml

So I have a data set I have successfully used to train a model, and have decent results. I am using a Two Class Boosted Decision tree for a Boolean output. So far so good.

I now want to analyze each column of my data set and remove any column that is not a meaningful influence on the outcome. I see statistics on columns in my data set:
[image]

But I don't see whether a column has a strong relationship with the output variable. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Some very helpful articles walked me through how to use the feature selection modules in Azure ML Studio:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/feature-selection-modules
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/filter-based-feature-selection

I used the "Filter Based Feature Selection" Module:

[image]

I added it to my training experiment and added input data.

[image]

I chose the feature I was training my model to predict.

[image]

After running the experiment I viewed the visualization of the Features:

[image]
[image]

Now I am using this to find which columns are valuable and which need some work.